# JQuery Dialog: Show Message in Dialog Box After Selecting Confirm Option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am using the JQuery dialog UI to have users confirm an action on the page.  If yes, an API call will be made and then window will redirect.  If no, the dialog closes.

Before the redirect, I'd like to show a "success" message within the actual dialog box, like "this action was performed".  Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Here's my code:

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: 
    {
        "Yes": function() 
        {


                    var request = '123';
            var url = '<?= $this->baseURL; ?>?rn=' + request;
                $.getJSON(url, function(data) {});  
            }


            var msg = 'Action performed';

                    //?   How do I display this message in the modal dialog window???

                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            var url = '<?= $this->moduleURL; ?>/cancel';        
            window.location.href = url; 


        },

        "Nevermind": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this may be a way, you empty your dialog div und append new text and set a timout and after 3 seconds the diloge closes and the redirect happens

```
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
resizable: false,
height:140,
modal: true,
buttons: 
{
    "Yes": function() 
    {


                var request = '123';
        var url = '<?= $this->baseURL; ?>?rn=' + request;
            $.getJSON(url, function(data) {});  
        }


        var msg = 'Action performed';

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).empty();

        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).text(msg);


 setTimeout(function() {
     $( this ).dialog( "close" );
       var url = '<?= $this->moduleURL; ?>/cancel';        
        window.location.href = url; 
}, 3000);



    },

    "Nevermind": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the AJAX method, and set async to false. This will make sure the request has returned before proceeding with the redirect.

To set the dialog content, you could just use `.html()`.

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: 140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            var request = '123';
            var url = '<?= $this->baseURL; ?>?rn=' + request;
            var msg = 'Action performed';
            $("#dialog-confirm").html(msg);

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: url,
                async: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close");
                    var url = '<?= $this->moduleURL; ?>/cancel';
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
            });
        },
        "Nevermind": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```